# Value from Ajax shows in console but it's not working as a Php value

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, console

i've got a little question regarding the usage of Ajax. I've done a search for the same issues but i can't find something to look alike with my problem.

Here is my code.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
$("#nume").blur(function() { 

numeform = $("#nume").val(); 

if (numeform){  
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
     url: "../../index.php",
         data: {numeform : numeform}, 
         cache: false,
        success: function(response) {
            data = numeform;
            console.log(data);                           
        } 
      });
    }
});
});
```

and in the php file i have

```
$data = $_POST['data'];
echo $data;
```

The console shows as it should. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working as a PHP value"? You make the ajax request and PHP responds, that's it.

Comment: `$numeform = $_POST['numeform']`

Answer (score 0):

The console is logging the variable you are sending not what you're receiving, that is why it looks correct. If you log `response` then you'd see a problem.

For the PHP part you're reading `$_POST['data']` when you should be reading `$_POST['numeform']` becuse that is what you sent in your ajax request

> {**numeform** : numeform}

Comment: I see .. so i was expecting something different. This back and forth data between the page requests / Ajax is baffling me. Anyhow i forgot to mention, I have tried with $numeform = $_POST['numeform'] also (as sugested by you and Andreas) earlier to no avail. From what i see if i log response i get the whole code of the page. I only want the #nume field from the index.

Comment: Do you go into php mode in your code `<?php` ? Is your server set up correctly to serve php pages?

Comment: echo '2'; works as it should .. as a test :) Should i test for something else?

Comment: If i use an external page like help.php to which i send the ajax POST in the index.php log (as response) i get the value that i want. Unfortunately i want the value in index not in help. If i leave it as it is .. the log response is the whole page including the right echo but it doesn't appear on the page.